# What exactly does the Android SDK Manager do?

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded the Android SDK only, without Android Studio, which I don't need.  For Windows, the SDK is delivered as a zip file, and you unpack it to the folder of your choice.  Following the unpacking, I ran the file *android.bat*, which launched the GUI for the SDK Manager and I downloaded further packages.

My question: Does the SDK Manager do anything other than downloading and unpacking packages?  For example, does it kick off any background processes or services?  And if so, how are those managed, since the GUI does not have means to control them?

PS: I'm tagging this question w/ Android Studio as it's the most closely related subject.

I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

"The Android SDK Manager provides the SDK tools, platforms, and other components you need to develop your apps."

So yes, it allows you to install and update the various versions of the Android SDKs and tools. It doesn't run any additional processes.